# Short story about a young engineer at a present day tech firm who finds that his manager has died at his desk

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story about an engineer at a tech firm, present day. It was published between 10 and 15 years ago. I recall it being in a collection of short stories and I associate it with Cory Doctorow, but I don't think he's the author.

The key point, called out in the introduction, is that the story mentions a lot of tech stuff that was common when the story was written. Even a decade earlier, the story would be twice as long because everything would need explanation: Amazon, Instagram, Spotify, Craigslist, even video chat. We don't think twice about doing these things on our phone in 2023. In 1995 they were all science fiction.

Here's the plot:

A young techie arrives at work and finds that his manager has died at his desk. He's the first to discover the body. He alerts the manager's assistant, an attractive young woman. They search the office and find a sheet of LSD. They decide to sell the acid on Craigslist. To do that, they have to test it. They decide that the assistant will take half a hit at home. They don't know each other well, so the assistant is leery of inviting the techie to her home. Instead, they set up a video conference so the techie can monitor remotely and be available to help if anything goes wrong, but she'll feel safe.

During the video conference they chat. She's a Burner, so he googles Burning Man. She's into certain bands, so he adds them to his Spotify list. He sees some books in the background, so he orders them from Amazon. Her Instagram shows that she's into rock climbing, so he googles local climbing gyms. Essentially, he's researching a possible relationship. It sounds a little stalker-y, but it comes from a good place.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Was this story included in a science fiction anthology, specifically?

Comment: I believe so. I think it was in a paperback collection, as opposed to a print magazine or online.

Comment: The description does not seem to contain any science fictional content.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no evidence has been provided that the work contains science fictional content.

Comment: Trying a drug that may have killed the person you found it on is so incredibly stupid I'd call it fantastical!

Comment: Update: It's "Code", by Bruce Sterling. It's in the collection "Visionary in Residence".

Comment: @Logan - What (if any) explicit sci-fi or fantasy elements does this story contain? It should contain such elements in order to be on-topic here, and it must be on-topic in order to be reopened.

Comment: Note: Sterling is an on-topic writer and the story is listed in ISFDb.  Also, we consider works on-topic if the were SF when written, even if real-world technology has surpassed the story

Comment: @DavidW - You were one of the users that voted for this question to be closed, which suggests that you didn't see anything in the question that you judged to be sci-fi or fantasy.

Comment: @LogicDictates The question says "10-15 years ago" at which time it might have been a slice-of-life story in a contemporary setting.  Since it was in fact >20 years, that pushes the described technologies into SF territory.  (At the time, which is the criterion used.)

Comment: Seems well closed. Let's not reopen, nothing scifi about this.

Comment: @DavidW - I fail to see what the identity of the author has to do with it. Are the Cormoran Strike novels on-topic because they were written by JK Rowling?

Comment: The description does not seem to contain any science fictional content.

Comment: @Valorum Because Sterling is a genre author, he has an ISFDb page.  ISFDb calls out non-genre works, but listed this story in with his genre oeuvre.  And our filter is not if it is science fiction _now_ but if it was when it was written.

Comment: Since it is open, I went ahead and added an answer. Since I didn't find the answer, and it's all basically copied blurbs, I did not own authorship.

Comment: I do find the author argument to be a weak one in this context. Surely Bruce Sterling is capable of writing standard fiction as well as science fiction. Perhaps he never does, but I'd prefer to judge that by assessing his stories on a case-by-case basis, rather than just assuming that a given story of his must be sci-fi based on other works he's known for. And if "Code" can be argued to be sci-fi for its time based on its own content, then that would be by far a more persuasive argument in my eyes than just pointing out who the author was.

Comment: Voting to close. The justifications in defense of this question are completely weak. That the author has written scifi is no excuse for including questions about non-scifi works without any scifi elements. Close it!

Comment: I read the story, and there did not appear to be anything SF about it.  Certainly, it shared themes with the author's SF, but everything was portrayed in a realistic (albeit silly) fashion for the time it was written.  That said, it seems unnecessary to argue about this too much.  It was a word by a recognized SF author, and it has been identified, so whether the question remains open or closed seems to be of very little long-term import.

Answer (score 3):

The querent has identified the story as "Code" ([ISFDB entry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?903496)), from the Bruce Sterling collection, *[Visionary in Residence](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/218564)*.

> I'm a science fiction writer. This is a golden opportunity to get up to most any mischief imaginable. With this fourth collection of my stories, I'm going to prove this to you. With these words, Bruce Sterling—author of New York times Notable Books of the Year and one of the great names in contemporary fiction—introduces his latest collection of thirteen tales. If you're familiar with his cyberpunk creations you won't be disappointed, but these stories range far beyond the limits of future technology. Visionary in Residence takes the reader to places never imagined and certainly where no one has ever been.

From [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/149551739):

> “Code” is from the Mainstream section. It’s about two junior employees discovering of the body of a key employee in a small company. It reads like SF, but all the technology used in the story is current; although Sterling does points out that if it had been published as recently as 1975 it would have nearly completely science fictional.